# conditional include in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

I am using Spring RestDoc together with AsciiDoc to describe my rest api. RestDoc generates different files depending if there are request parameters described / response fields etc. I would like to have one template conditionally including whatever file exists.

something like this:

```
Request:

include::{reqresPath}/http-request.adoc[]

Response:
include::{reqresPath}/http-response.adoc[]

Parameters:
ifeval::[{{reqresPath}/request-parameters.adoc}.exists]
  include::{reqresPath}/request-parameters.adoc[]
endif::[]
ifeval::[{{reqresPath}/request-parameters.adoc}.exists]
  include::{reqresPath}/request-parameters.adoc[]
endif::[]
```

or at least exclude warnings in case of a missing file. But I could not figure out how to suppress these.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, where is [no operator](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/directives/ifeval/) for `ifeval` available, which can be used to check the existence of a file.

The way I would go is to write an [extension for Asciidoctor](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/extensions/), which can also be done by using Java. If your projects is big enough, I would suggest to go for this solution.

Comment: Today there is such an extension that you can do that, and many more

https://github.com/verhas/jamal/

Answer (score 0):

The most extreme way is to make a custom TemplatedSnippet which is generating an empty snippet to be included...

I hope there is a better way to do this.

Edit:
Take a look of http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#by-tagged-regions